# What is the difference between Class<? extends T> and Class<? extends ?> in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I was going through the some legacy code in my application and I found uses of Java generics.

Can you please tell me, what is the difference between

```
Class<? extends T>
```

and

```
Class<? extends ?>
```

I am not clear about how and when to use these generics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Comment: @Akceptor That duplicate doesn't apply here

Comment: Could you please provide more context, `? extends ?` makes no sense and would yield a compilation error.

Answer (score 4):

`Class<? extends ?>` is not valid type in java.

`Class<? extends T>` is valid type in java.

Comment: Did you mean _va**l**id_?

Answer (score 1):

`Class<? extends T`> example:

`Class<? extends Number>` can be `Class<Number>`, `Class<Integer>`, `Class<BigDecimal>` etc... In other words **any** Class that **extends** `Number` class. That is checked in *compile* time!

On the other hand `Class<? extends ?>` can be interpreted as class of type **any class which extend any class** and that is a nonsense.

EDIT:
You're asking for usage. Here is an example of code that uses `List<? extends Number>` to calculate sum and average of all numbers in the list:

```
public class Help {

    private static BigDecimal sum(List<? extends Number> list) {
        return list == null || list.isEmpty() ?
                BigDecimal.ZERO :
                list.stream()
                        .map(n -> new BigDecimal(n.doubleValue()))
                        .reduce(BigDecimal::add)
                        .get();
    }

    private static BigDecimal average(List<? extends Number> list) {
        return list == null || list.isEmpty() ?
                BigDecimal.ZERO :
                sum(list).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(list.size()), MathContext.DECIMAL32);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Number> numbers =
                List.of(
                        1.0D,                           /*double*/
                        2.0F,                           /*float*/
                        3L,                             /*long*/
                        new BigInteger("4"),            /*BigInteger*/
                        new AtomicInteger(5),           /*just for test*/
                        (int)'a'                        /*int*/
                );

        System.out.println("sun of " + numbers + " = " + sum(numbers));
        System.out.println("avg of " + numbers + " = " + average(numbers));
        System.out.println("sum of empty list = " + sum(List.of()));
        System.out.println("avg of empty list = " + average(List.of()));
        System.out.println("sum of null list = " + sum(null));
        System.out.println("avg of null list = " + average(null));

    }
}
```

I hope that you can get some basic tips from this code.